# Arraylists and Flatfile Databases

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that saves a list of strings to a file and then reads them into an arraylist. Here is my current code.

```
ObjectInputStream input = null;

    try {
        input = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("friends.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        File f = new File("friends.txt");
        try {
            f.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String obj;

    try {
        while ((obj = (String)input.readObject()) != null) {
            friendly.add(obj);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

This returns a null pointer exception. I am not quite sure what is going wrong here.

Comment: Please provide the stack trace details.

Comment: Use a debugger to step through your code and figure out what is `null`. Then fix it.

Comment: And a hint as to the correspondence between the line numbers in the stack trace and the posted code?

Comment: Thanks Greg. I am relatively new to java and I didn't even realize that was there.

Comment: @pki: Yep - that's why we wanted to see the stack trace - so we could look at what line it was. :-)

Comment: It is the line that the while loop is on so I am going to switch the way I did this. Use an if statement to determine the file is existent. If its not then create one. Then read each line of that file into the array with a for loop. I just dont know how I am going to write out.

Comment: Thank you to all of you who helped me on this. I got it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, for one thing, if the file doesn't exist, 'input' will be null.

I'm not quite sure what the rationale is for handling the case of the file not existing in the way that you do-- why not just test for the existence via File.exists() and only perform the opening and reading if it exists?

Other than that, as another commentator has said, provide a stack trace for a start.

Comment: OK, but they're reading, aren't they? I assume they want to cope with the case where the file hasn't been written yet (or something...).

Comment: Yeah - I take it all back. Brain fade. *Input* stream not output stream. :-)